# MD5 в текстовом режиме?

Tags: linux, bash, linux-mint, md5

Читаю справку по подсчёту md5

```
$ md5sum --help
```

и вижу там странные параметры:

> ```
> -b, --binary            читать в двоичном режиме
> -t, --text              читать в текстовом режиме (по умолчанию)
> ```

Чем отличаются режимы и почему по умолчанию текстовый?

Единственное, что приходит в голову - сишная замена `\r\n` на `\n`, но ведь в линуксе она не используется? Есть что-то ещё?

Вот полный вывод команды:

```
Использование: md5sum [КЛЮЧ]… [ФАЙЛ]…
Печатает или проверяет контрольные суммы MD5 (128-битные).
Если ФАЙЛ не задан или задан как -, читает стандартный ввод.

  -b, --binary            читать в двоичном режиме
  -c, --check             читать суммы MD5 из ФАЙЛОВ и сверять их
      --tag               создать контрольную сумму в стиле BSD
  -t, --text              читать в текстовом режиме (по умолчанию)

Три следующих ключа полезны только при проверке контрольных сумм:
      --quiet             не выводить OK для каждого успешно проверенного файла
      --status            не производить вывод, выходное значение показывает
                          успех проверки
  -w, --warn              предупреждать о неправильно составленных строках в
                          списке контрольных сумм

      --strict            с --check завершить работу с ненулевым кодом при
                          любых некорректных входных данных
      --help     показать эту справку и выйти
      --version  показать информацию о версии и выйти

Метод вычисления контрольных сумм описан в RFC 1321. Входными данными при
проверке должны быть полученные ранее выходные данные этой программы.
По умолчанию печатает строку с контрольной суммой, знак, показывающий
режим ввода («*» для двоичных, пробел для текстовых) и имя каждого ФАЙЛА.

Об ошибках в md5sum сообщайте по адресу bug-coreutils@gnu.org.
Домашняя страница GNU coreutils: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/>
Справка по работе с программами GNU: <http://www.gnu.org/gethelp/>
Об ошибках в переводе сообщений «md5sum» сообщайте по адресу <gnu@mx.ru>
Полная документация доступна по команде: info coreutils 'md5sum invocation'
```

Comment: *в линуксе она не используется?* -- а кто сказал, что файлы, для которых считается MD5, создаются исключительно под линуксом?

Comment: @PinkTux, у меня есть файл. Я в линуксе с него считаю md5. Откуда бы этой утилите знать, где я его создал? Я как-то ожидаю по умолчанию md5 бинарного файла без всяких выкрутасов. А тут мне вдруг говорят про текстовый режим по умолчанию. Эм?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для версии [`md5sum` из GNU Coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/md5sum-invocation.html) это **системозависимо**.

- В Linux действительно нет никакой разницы.

  > `-b, --binary`
  >
  > ... On systems like GNU that do not distinguish between binary and text files, this option merely flags each input mode as binary: the MD5 checksum is unaffected. ...

  То есть, под линуксом этот флаг никак не повлияет на значение контрольной суммы.
- ...а на системах, где бинарный режим *существенен* (Windows, DOS):

  > ... This option is the default on systems like MS-DOS that distinguish between binary and text files, except for reading standard input when standard input is a terminal. ...

  ...**бинарный режим по умолчанию** (с оговоркой: кроме как для stdin из терминала).

Т. е. в конечном счёте с настройками по умолчанию должны на одинаковых файлах получаться одинаковые результаты на любой системе; что от хэширования и ожидается.

Текстовый режим по умолчанию, скорее всего, унаследован у `fopen`, который использует текстовый режим, только если явно не добавить в строку режима букву `b`. Также возможно, что бинарный режим просто был добавлен позднее (когда дошло до портирования на системы, где бинарный режим *имеет значение*), и текстовый режим по умолчанию оставлен для обратной совместимости.

Comment: В описании ещё написано, что выводится звёздочка перед именем файла в бинарном режиме. Проверил - действительно так. А в текстовом не выводится. И по умолчанию не выводится. Значит, по умолчанию действительно текстовый. На мой взгляд, нелогично. Но хоть контрольная сумма в линуксе будет верная независимо от режима.

Comment: Интересная мысль про совместимость.